How to run pyinstaller with dependency on GTK3-runtime Win64?
dear all:
I am writing a Windows app in Python 3.11.
My app uses cairosvg which needs GTK3-runtime to work in Windows.
At this moment, I need tell the users to manually download and install GTK3-runtime, and then update the environment variable PATH.
Can I package the python scripts with GTK3-runtime Win64 using the hidden imports options of pyinstaller?  I am not sure how to write down this option for GTK3-runtime win64 or whether this can be done.
Moreover, do I need python script to change the PATH environment variable after GTK3-runtime win64 is downloaded to the client side?  If I need to do that, can someone drop me a few lines of python scripts to do this?
Thanks
Farn
